# proper syntax for accessing values from dictionary

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I have the following code that generates a dictionary of key/value pairs in php:

```
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
 $obj = json_decode($json);
 print_r(json_encode($obj));
```

print_r produces the following output:

```
{"email":"someemail@gmail.com","password":"compas"}
```

how do you output just the value of the email key?  Why doesn't $obj["email"] work?

Comment: why are you json_encoding it? that makes it a string. `$obj = json_decode($json);` then `$email = $obj->email`. If you want an associative array, `$obj = json_decode($json, true);` then `$email = $obj['email']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn the json_decode to an arry use following form see [manual](https://www.php.net/json_decode)

```
$myjson = '{"email":"someemail@gmail.com","password":"compas"}';
$obj = json_decode($myjson,true);
print_r($obj[email]);
```

returns `someemail@gmail.com`

Comment: This is a clear duplicate

Comment: Voting to close and answering isn't really compatible